# What is the correct phone number format to send an SMS to Mexico on Twilio?

Tags: sms, twilio

I am trying to send an SMS to Mexico via Twilio. The Mexican country code is 52 and the area code I am sending to is 667.

I have tried the following

+521667xxxxxxx - which I believe to be correct based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Mexico#Dialing_a_cell_phone_in_Mexico_from_abroad

+011521667xxxxxxx

+001521667xxxxxxx

+52667xxxxxxx

I get the following error from twilio - "is not a mobile number"

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but people might still wonder about this, so here it goes:
+521667xxxxxxx used to be correct up until August 3rd, 2019. The correct format is +52667xxxxxxx since then. Even now you may have varying degrees of success using the former format since telecom companies are still allowing it, but you should use the new one to avoid problems in the future.
You can confirm this information here: https://www.mexperience.com/mexico-simplifies-telephone-dialing-rules/ (one of the few sources in English I could find)

With respect to the specific number you were trying, it really might not be a mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

According to the twilio docs it would be +53667xxxxxxx. You may also have to enable international messaging

[Twilio International Numbers](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-dial-international-numbers-with-twilio)

[Enabled International Dialing Permissions](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/does-twilio-support-dialing-international-phone-numbers)